# Authentication in a replica set

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replication

When I tested the authentication in a test environment, everything worked fine.  The only difference was I was not using a replica set. I read that I might need to use a key file to authenticate with a username and password if using replication, but my supervisor wants to stay away from keyfiles if possible.  Is there a way to do it without a keyfile, while still using username/password ?

In my log file, I see lines like these:

```
[conn4552] Successfully authenticated as principal DBAdmin on admin

[conn1] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", configVersion: 1, hbv: 1, from: "172.30.1.216:27017", fromId: 1, term: 8, $replData: 1, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1527610291, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, FA0631F3EE81E932FE5E49031F76A9E5199250A0), keyId: 6561016230625411073 } }, $db: "admin" }

[replexec-27] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 22357) to <IP>:<PORT>, response status: Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command {  replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", configVersion: 1, hbv: 1, from: "<IP>:<PORT>", fromId: 0, term: 8, $replData: 1, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1527610291, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, FA0631F3EE81E932FE5E49031F76A9E5199250A0), keyId: 6561016230625411073 } }, $db: "admin" }
```

Comment: I can't find a solution to this without using a keyfile. What does your supervisor have against keyfiles? Doesn't he like authentication?

Comment: It just isn't all that secure.  From what I have read, using a keyfile is not recommended for the production environment.  Is restricting access to a keyfile using Active Directory secure enough?

Comment: I went ahead and used a keyfile.  Not ideal, but the problem is solved.

Comment: A keyfile is only used for the internal authentication anyway. What were your reasons to not use one? MongoDB Docs state that a keyfile is not recommended for Production and that they recommend using x.509 certificates instead. You could look at using x.509 certificates?